# if New MQ (message queue) is added to the existing functionality, then new properties file needs to be created?

Tags: mq, properties-file

In existing functionality application will be keep on listening to MQ and when message arrives to MQ, programs which are injected through springs are called and messages are read as JMSByteMessage and parsed and written to oracle database.

Requirement is new and different form of XML are sent to new queues, so existing listening programs will do the required job for reading the new messages. but new functionality needs to added for new XMLs.

My question is, because new queue information/configuration should be done in properties file. so, new queue information/configuration are to be mentioned in same properties file with different variable or new property file is needs to be created for new queue information/configuration?

Comment: Is your question about MQ configuration? And it's it IBM MQ or something else? Sorry but it's not clear to me

Comment: Jeevan, please update the question to clarify which MQ you are working with a sample of the properties file that you are using.  (Spring annotations?  JMS Properties? JNDI .bindings?)  If the question is not improved it will be deleted as being too vague to answer.